# Can find the angles of the triangle created by 3 points if I have each points compass bearing?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am currently researching using magnetometers and radio field strength of 3 points for localisation. Is it possible to use the compass heading of 3 points to work out the angles of the triangle they create?

the diagram can be found at this link (unfortunately not enough rep to post images yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HY7o.jpg

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

In the diagram, the solid black arrows are the bearings I will have with the angle relevant to north. I want to find the angles between each of the blue lines. I will also have a rough estimate of the length of the blue lines. I fear though that as the angles give no information about the other robots, there isn't much hope of finding the triangle's angles.

Comment: You could do what I did: I bought a cheap one-page scanner that makes jpegs. If I draw a diagram on ordinary paper, I make a jpeg of that. Then I save it to my home computer. Finally, there is an icon for loading images during edit, I think it resembles an oil painting. You can load the image into your question. Yes, an oil painting. The image is then also hosted at some service, and displayed here. Jpegs work better than pdfs.

Comment: You're trying to get something out of nothing, aren't you? If I understand your question, the robots know nothing about their positions relative to each other. As a thought experiment, pick up robot C and move it ten metres west. None of the bearings have changed, but the triangle has become completely different.

Comment: @TonyK Yep - I realised this when I thought about them being all facing due north eg 0 deg. Can't make anything out of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all three edge lengths of a triangle, all three angles can be found using the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). If the triangle is large enough for the curvature of the Earth to make any difference, there are two versions of a ***spherical*** [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines). Spherical geometry and trigonometry are well documented, as, for many centuries, they have formed the basis for celestial navigation.

EDIT: if I were doing this, with approximate edge lengths, I would check for errors using both sum of the angles being 180 degrees and the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: No, I would be one of the points. The points are all moving robots where the magnetic bearing from north is known. I don't know if there is any way to use these bearings to find the location of each of the points relevant to the other 2.

Comment: @markmcmurray, please post a diagram, carefully labelled, all points and all edges that are relevant, and identify what you will know and what you won't.

Comment: I've posted an edit with a link to a diagram - it's not the best labelled but hopefully my explanation will fill in the blanks. All three line lengths will be known (estimated) and the bearing of each bot is known to all bots.

Comment: @markmcmurray, a bearing is what, a direction of travel?

Comment: Yes - well the direction the bot is facing

Comment: @markmcmurray Revised my answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Shall use that and just have to save my magnetometer  for giving the robots a direction of travel to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the compass heading from each point to each of the other two, you have measured the angles-just take the difference of the headings.  Even if it is a large triangle so the compass deviation varies between the points and the angles don't add to $180^\circ$, the measurement of the two angles is local and applies.

Comment: The points are moving robots and I only have the compass heading from magnetic north at each point though which is what is confusing me. Like say they are all pointing north, I don't know if there is any way to work out the angles between them?

Comment: @markmcmurray, please post a diagram as an edit to your question.

Comment: OK. Will attempt one now

Comment: So the compass heading is the direction of travel of each robot relative to north?  That gives you no information about where the others are, so no.

Comment: @RossMillikan, we should wait on his diagram. I had a job interview once, a place was trying to build the next Wii type game controller, using internal accelerometers and a compass. I told them they had five pieces of information but six degrees of freedom. No job, although that was never really a question once they saw I was over 40.

Comment: @RossMillikan I feel that you are probably correct.

Comment: @WillJagy - any other pieces of information you think I might beable to use to find the angles?

Comment: You either need bearings from one to another or coordinates. Maybe you can get coordinates from integrating the velocity.

Comment: Think I will just have to stick to the field strength estimated distances. Thanks.